# pythonic conversion of list of lists to strings by column

Tags: python

i have a list of lists corresponding to an array (each list inside the list has the same number of entries):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

i'd like to convert this to a single string:

```
"1,4,7\t2,4,8\t3,6,9"
```

ie make each column be a comma separated list of string values from `a`. my solution with numpy arrays is quite a hack:

```
b = array(b)
l = len(a)
result = "\t".join([",".join(map(str, b[:,r])) for r in range(l)])
```

is there a more elegant way to do this? thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can transpose a list of lists using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Everything else is simple:

```
>>> "\t".join(",".join(map(str, r)) for r in zip(*a))
'1,4,7\t2,5,8\t3,6,9'
```

Comment: It took me aaaages to understand this idiom! You regard the rows of the matrix as separate iterables, and `zip` takes the first element from each of these, then the second, then the third, ... so it returns tuples of columns. And this is the transpose of the original matrix!

Answer (score 3):

Use [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function to get

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>>
```

and than do your thing.

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b = zip(*a)
>>> result = "\t".join([",".join(map(str, r)) for r in b])
>>> result
'1,4,7\t2,5,8\t3,6,9'
>>>
```

Comment: No need for the `[]`; the argument to `"\t".join` can just be a genexp.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this much faster with numpy itself like this:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> numpy.savetxt(s, a.T, fmt="%d", delimiter=",", newline="\t")
>>> s.getvalue()
'1,4,7\t2,5,8\t3,6,9\t'
```

This doesn't require allocating extra memory copying the array because `.T` returns a view of the array, not a copy. Numpy's savetext function should also be faster than doing this in python.

Comment: `a.swapaxes(0, 1)` is usually abbreviated to `a.T` for a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @SvenMarnach nice catch, not sure why I didn't use ``.T``. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are already **better** solutions with `zip()`, but this should do the trick too:

```
>>> '\t'.join(','.join(str(b[j]) for b in a) for j in range(len(a)))
'1,4,7\t2,5,8\t3,6,9'
```